# Can't find StackOverflow exception

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, ef-core-3.1

I'm migrating a very large chunk of files (let's say 500k, 700gb) from database to minio file storage. I use this console app. But there is a memory leak, it stops with StackOverflow exception and I can't find the reason:

```
        var watch = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew();

        Console.WriteLine("\n");

        Console.WriteLine("Starting migration");

        Console.WriteLine("Getting metadata");

        var attachments = await dbContext.Attachments.ToListAsync();

        Console.WriteLine("Getting metadata completed");
        Console.WriteLine($"Total number of attachments: {attachments.Count}");

        Console.WriteLine("\n");

        int total = 0;
        int completed = 0;
        int faulted = 0;
        bool fileAlreadyMigrated = false;
        using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("migrationLogs.txt"))
        {
            foreach (var attachment in attachments)
            {
                total++;

                Console.WriteLine($"Begin migration of attachment with id: {attachment.Id}. Total {total}/{attachments.Count} ({((double)total / (double)attachments.Count) * 100: 00.##}%)");
                sw.WriteLine($"Begin migration of attachment with id: {attachment.Id}. Total {total}/{attachments.Count} ({((double)total / (double)attachments.Count) * 100: 00.##}%)");
                attachment.Migrated = false;
                attachment.Faulted = false;
                try
                {
                    fileAlreadyMigrated = false;
                    using (var migratedData = new StreamReader("migratedData.txt"))
                    {
                        while (migratedData.Peek() != -1)
                        {
                            if (Guid.Parse(migratedData.ReadLine()) == attachment.Id)
                                fileAlreadyMigrated = true;
                        }
                    }
                    if (!fileAlreadyMigrated)
                    {
                        var binary = await dbContext.AttachmentBinaries.FirstOrDefaultAsync(b => b.BinaryId == attachment.BinaryId);

                        attachment.FileBinary = binary.FileInBinary;

                        var res = await storageService.UploadBinary(attachment);
                        if (res == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine($"The migration of attachment with id: {attachment.Id} is completed successfully.");
                            sw.WriteLine($"The migration of attachment with id: {attachment.Id} is completed successfully.");
                            attachment.Migrated = true;
                            completed++;
                            File.AppendAllText("migratedData.txt", attachment.Id + Environment.NewLine);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine($"The migration of attachment with id: {attachment.Id} is faulted.\nError: {res.ToString()}");
                            sw.WriteLine($"The migration of attachment with id: {attachment.Id} is faulted.\nError: {res.ToString()}");

                            attachment.Faulted = true;
                            faulted++;
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        continue;
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"The migration of attachment with id: {attachment.Id} is faulted.\nError: {e.Message} {e.InnerException?.Message}");
                    sw.WriteLine($"The migration of attachment with id: {attachment.Id} is faulted.\nError: {e.Message} {e.InnerException?.Message}");
                    attachment.Faulted = true;
                    faulted++;
                }

                Console.WriteLine("\n");
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
            }



            watch.Stop();
            var timeStamp = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(watch.ElapsedMilliseconds);

            Console.WriteLine($"Migration completed in {timeStamp.Hours:###00}:{timeStamp.Minutes:00}:{timeStamp.Seconds:00},{timeStamp.Milliseconds}");
            Console.WriteLine($"Total attachments processed: {total}");
            Console.WriteLine($"Successful: {completed}");
            Console.WriteLine($"Faulted: {faulted}");
            Console.WriteLine($"Success rate: {((double)completed / (double)total) * 100:00.##}%");

            Console.WriteLine("\n");

            sw.WriteLine($"Migration completed in {timeStamp.Hours:###00}:{timeStamp.Minutes:00}:{timeStamp.Seconds:00},{timeStamp.Milliseconds}");
            sw.WriteLine($"Total attachments processed: {total}");
            sw.WriteLine($"Successful: {completed}");
            sw.WriteLine($"Faulted: {faulted}");
            sw.WriteLine($"Success rate: {((double)completed / (double)total) * 100:00.##}%");

            sw.WriteLine("\n");
            var userInput = string.Empty;
            do
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Retreive the list of unsucsessfullly migrated attachments ids? (Y/N)");
                userInput = Console.ReadLine();
            }
            while (userInput.ToLower() != "y" && userInput.ToLower() != "n");

            if (userInput.ToLower() == "y")
            {
                foreach (var attachment in attachments.Where(a => a.Faulted))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(attachment.Id);
                }
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine("\n");
    }
```

UploadBinary:

```
    public async Task<HttpStatusCode> UploadBinary(Attachment dto)
    {
        var response = await httpService.SendPostRequestAsync<Attachment>(/*$"{storageUrl}upload"*/storageUrl, dto);
        return response;
    }
```

I assume it's something related to dbContext being open for too long or not using AsNoTracking(), but I'm not sure. Can anybody help?

Edit 1. First obvious problem was this line:

```
  attachment.FileBinary = binary.FileInBinary;
```

since there is iteration through attachment objects, on each step it added file binary (which was not mapped) to an object, increasing ram. Writing binary to a variable made ram grow slower, but still it grew on each iteration. Only after I changed that part to

```
var fileInBinary = dbContext.AttachmentBinaries.AsNoTracking().FirstOrDefault(b => b.BinaryId == attachment.BinaryId).FileInBinary;
var res = storageService.UploadBinary(attachment, fileInBinary);
Array.Clear(fileInBinary, 0, fileInBinary.Length);
```

problem was solved. I still don't understand why I have to explicitly clear the array, since GC should dispose it on each iteration because there are no references left to it.

Comment: Dou you have the stack trace? Can't you see any clue? You can open the Windows Event Viewer, perhaps the exception is traced there.

Comment: A StackOverflow exception is not a memory leak in any normal sense, its just you using up the entire stack. This is usually caused by (though not limited to) recursion, is this code recursive in any way?

Comment: I don't think it's related to the issue, but I'd suggest to _actually_ use logging framework to write logs.

Comment: Does your console output give you any pointers?

Comment: My first suspicion would be `var binary = await dbContext.AttachmentBinaries.FirstOrDefaultAsync(b => b.BinaryId == attachment.BinaryId);` and following. You seem to load whole files into memory? Maybe a streaming approach would be better ...

Comment: This code begs to be broken into methods. It's *very* hard to read it. Exporting files using EF Core is the most *in*efficient way possible though. Trying to load an entire 2GB blob in memory using EF is guaranteed to cause huge delays and problems.

Comment: @Marc, there are mostly lots of 
Windows successfully diagnosed a low virtual memory condition. The following programs consumed the most virtual memory: ProcureBinaryMigrator.exe (3884) consumed 27839094784 bytes, MsMpEng.exe (1984) consumed 289169408 bytes, and NisSrv.exe (1916) consumed 133857280 bytes.

Comment: @Jamil first, don't use EF Core. You have no Objects and Relations, you have BLOBs. Use ADO.NET to read the BLOBs as streams using [SqlDataReader.GetStream()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getstream?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0) instead of `byte[]` arrays and copy the stream contents to the output folder. You can use `Stream.CopyTo` or `CopyToAsync` for this

Comment: @Jamil as TheGeneral says below my comment, StackOverflow it's not (only) a memory problem... in the stacktrace you sould see the trace of calls between methods and you sould have an idea of the origin (sometimes it's not clear on StackOverflow exceptions)

Comment: A stack-overflow is almost always caused by *either* recursion (usually infinite recursion), *or* by `stackalloc`-heavy code; assuming you don't have any of the latter, the former would be the first thing to look at - which usually means: stepping through or tracing to find where exactly it goes down a rabbit hole of deep, deep calls; this can usually be done with the debugger, or by adding logging code to narrow down how far it gets - add more detail there, repeat, etc

Comment: @mjwills OP is unlikely to be able to properly `catch` a stack-overflow; it is usually pretty terminal

Comment: @ChrisBD no, it doesn't

Comment: @Marc, I don't have studio there. Can probably log stacktrace, will try to do it

Comment: @MarcGravell thanks, will try that

Comment: A fair point @MarcGravell.

Comment: I edited the post, but still don't know why it works. Explanation appreciated